# IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before wait()

Tags: java, android, multithreading, wait, java-threads

**I know that there are a lot of similar questions, but no one helped me.** I am getting `IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before wait()` when I try to pause the thread.

Here is my initialization method:

```
// called only once in constructor; the variables are global ( private Thread ... )
    public void init() {

        recordingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                isNewRecordingThread= false;
                record();
            }
        });

        recognitionThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                isNewRecognition= false;
                recognize();
            }
        });
...
}
```

startRecording method:

```
private synchronized void startRecording(Thread recordingThread) {
    if(isNewRecordingThread){
        recordingThread.start();
        return;
    }
    recordingThread.notify();
}
```

startRecognition method:

```
private synchronized void startRecognition(Thread recognitionThread) {
    shouldContinueRecognition = true;
    if(isNewRecognition){
        recognitionThread.start();
        return;
    }
    recognitionThread.notify();
}
```

And the stopping method where I actually get the error:

```
private synchronized void stopRecordingAndRecognition(Thread recordingThread, Thread recognitionThread) {
    try{
        if (recordingThread != null && recordingThread.isAlive()) {
            recordingThread.wait();
        }
        if (recognitionThread != null && recognitionThread.isAlive()) {
            recognitionThread.wait();
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e){
        Log.d("TESTING","InterruptedException e= "+e);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to call `wait()/await()` without loop because you can miss a signal or have a spurious wake-up!

Comment: Any ideas how to make it better ?

Comment: @abrutsze how can we make it better if we don't know what you want to achieve.

Comment: The goal is to start thread, pause it and after resume

Comment: @abrutsze I have added a code snippet for pausing/resuming a thread.

Answer (score 1):

"object not locked by thread before wait()"

Think, what object is meant in this message? That very object for which `wait()` is applied:

```
recordingThread.wait();
```

that is, `recordingThread`.

`synchronized void stopRecordingAndRecognition` is irrelevant because it locks `this` object, and not `recordingThread`.

So, there are 2 solutions:

- force methods to synchronize on `recordingThread`
- embed synchronized methods into the class of `recordingThread`

Comment: can you give a bit more information about how exactly to implement any of your solutions, please ?

Comment: @abrutsze see my another answer

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, because it explains a common mistake. :)

Answer (score 1):

"The goal is to start thread, pause it and after resume"

Pausing and resuming threads in Java is a bad practice because leads to subtle and hard to debug errors.

The only reliable way to stop/resume some computational process is to split this process into parts, process that parts in a loop, and before the start of processing the next part, checking if processing is allowed.

As an evolution of this approach, each part is formed as a `Runnable` and is submitted to a single-threaded `Executor`. Instead of stop and resume the `Executor`, producer thread(s) simply stop and resume submitting the partial tasks to the executor.

If (some) parts can be processed in parallel, then multithreaded executor can be used, but it requires coordination between submitting particular tasks.

Comment: Thanks, will check it. :)

Answer (score 1):

> The goal is to start thread, pause it and after resume

Here is a code snippet that I use for suspending and resuming a thread.

```
public class ThreadStatus { 
    private boolean paused;
    private final String threadName;
    private final ReentrantLock lock;
    private final Condition condition;

    public ThreadStatus (String name) {
        threadName = name;
        lock = new ReentrantLock();
        condition = lock.newCondition();
        paused = false;
    }

    // check for the thread to be paused
    public void checkForPause() {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            while (paused) {                
                condition.await();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            // interrupted
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    // Pause the thread
    public void pause() {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            paused = true;
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    // Resume the thread
    public void resume() {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            paused = false;
            condition.signalAll();
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return threadName;
    }
}
```

If you need you could implement `isStopped()` or `isRunning()` similarly.

```
final ThreadStatus threadStatus = new ThreadStatus("Thread-A");
```

In the client code, call `threadStatus.checkForPause()` at the relevant point. For example, if you have some repeated processings inside a loop, you can do something like -

```
while (!threadStatus.isStopped()) {
      threadStatus.checkForPause();   

     // do your processing here
}
```

Comment: Thanks, will check it. :)